# PHP Performance poor on CentOS

Tags: php, ubuntu, centos

I've got a question about the performance of PHP (any version) on CentOS vs Ubuntu 16.04

When i call a simple textfile with wrk, i get about 30k requests/s on both OS'es, which is perfectly fine.

But when i call a simple echo command in an PHP file, the performance drop slightly on Ubuntu which makes sense.

But on CentOS it drops to 12/13k request/s which is unacceptable.

I've tested this on the most basic setup but i can't seem to find any logical explanation for this.
My thought was that SELinux could have anything to do with this, but setting SELinux to permissive or disabling it doesn't affect the performance at all.

There is also no difference in using PHP-FPM or mod PHP.

Did anyone else ever experienced this or could point me in the right direction?

Comment: How `performance drop slightly on Ubuntu which makes sense` to you?
What is number of requests on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Hassaan On Ubuntu it goed from ~30k to ~27k request/s

Comment: CentOS Version?

Comment: Apache versions are the same? What happens with an `index.php` file which has no PHP, just `Hello world`?

Comment: `LSB Version: :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description: CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
Release: 7.4.1708
Codename: Core`

Performance with only 'Hello world' in the .php file is just as bad as when i use `echo 'hello world';`

Comment: @JeroenBleijenberg Apache & PHP versions are same?

Comment: @Hassaan yes :) even on the latest version of Apache (2.4.25), this problem still occurs

Comment: Voting to close this as way too broad. There is huge scope for tuning the behaviour of the filesystem, network stack, memory and CPU scheduler, apache input and output buffers even before considering PHP. Just listing the minimal amount of information to gather goes way beyond the scope of a QandA here.

Comment: @symcbean ofcourse, you could ask for information you want instead of "just closing it". Because i clearly have no idea where to start looking. Or atleast point someone in a direction where to look instead of just saying "ugh, close it because not enough info". You know, we're not all on the same level as you are

Answer (score 0):

This could be issue of PHP version. CentOS 7 has `PHP5.6` by default and Ubuntu have `PHP7`.

PHP7 is more speed then older versions. You can google for `PHP 5.6 vs PHP 7 Performance Comparison`.

You can **upgrade php** on CentOS and test again by using following commands on Terminal.

See currently installed php version

```
php --version
```

> Download Remi and EPEL Repository packages

```
wget -q http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
wget -q https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

> Enable Remi and EPEL Repository

```
rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

// FOR PHP 7.0 EXECUTE:
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70

// FOR PHP 7.1 EXECUTE:
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71
```

> Install or Upgrade to PHP 7

```
yum install php
```